# Cisco Redistribute of SVI routes into BGP

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco Nexus and i have 250x SVI on them and each SVI has different prefixes, this sample from one my SVIs :

```
    interface VlanXXXXX
  description USER
  no shutdown
  no ip redirects
  ip address x.x.x.1/29
  ip address x.x.x.57/29 secondary
  ip address x.x.x.189/30 secondary
  ip policy route-map YYYYY
```

is there any that announce .1/32 and .57/32 and .189/30 into one of my bgp neighbor? because i want to announce my interface gateway IP to another device and do some inspection there,
i know i can manually announe them in BGP but they are around 300x prefixes and adjust them ad tune them are hard works so i am looking for a dynamic way.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to redistribute connected?

Comment: if i do this it will announce x.x.x.0/29 or x.x.x.56/29 or ... , i just need the announce only gateway IP, if you check my interface vlan config i need to announce .1/32 and .57/32 and .189/32 to my neighbour

Comment: you can specify a tag on IP addresses (...and routes, etc).  It might look like `ip address x.x.x.1/29 tag 999` as an example.  You would then configure a route-map to redistribute connected routes that also match on that tag value.  The idea is that you can configure that tag on as many IP's as you'd like - or, indeed, use different sets of tags to influence different route behaviors.

Comment: ok i know but if i announce tag 999 then it will announce x.x.x.1/29 and i want to announce only first IP, the gateway!